# Добавление ссылок на сайт из списка

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x

Делаю парсер на питоне с использованием HTML(eel). Возникла проблема обработки списков, которые нужно отобразить на сайте

Есть python скрипт который возвращает такой список:

```
['https://vk.com/wall-96272534_127905', 'https://vk.com/wall-167488072_99276', 'https://vk.com/wall-152141431_23483', 'https://vk.com/wall-109823946_270184', 'https://vk.com/wall-31480508_900224', 'https://vk.com/wall-149680278_81652', 'https://vk.com/wall-133030665_723987', 'https://vk.com/wall-33964060_773077', 'https://vk.com/wall-129440544_860570']
```

Нужно как-то данный список расположить на сайте отдельными ссылками, чтоб было как-то так

```
<a href="https://vk.com/wall-96272534_127905"></a>
```

В данный момент это выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     async function vkmessage(){
      let post = await eel.userPost(user)();
      document.getElementById("POST1").innerHTML=post;
     }
         jQuery('#show').on('click',function(){
                            vkmessage();
         });
     </script>
```

Из-за моего незнания решил просто соединить элементы списка в сплошную строку и простой вставкой вставить на сайт. Но хотелось бы, чтобы это был не просто текст, а именно отдельные ссылки.

Answer (score 2):

Можно пройтись перебирающим методом по массиву ссылок и создать по тегу `а` с соответствующим `href`'ом и добавить тег в нужный контейнер в конце.

```
// контейнер, в который будем добавлять ссылки
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const links = ['https://vk.com/wall-96272534_127905', 'https://vk.com/wall-167488072_99276', 'https://vk.com/wall-152141431_23483', 'https://vk.com/wall-109823946_270184', 'https://vk.com/wall-31480508_900224', 'https://vk.com/wall-149680278_81652', 'https://vk.com/wall-133030665_723987', 'https://vk.com/wall-33964060_773077', 'https://vk.com/wall-129440544_860570'];

links.forEach((link) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a'); // создаем тег
  a.setAttribute('href', link); // добавляем url в href
  // добавляем стиль для того, чтобы ссылки добавлялись в столбик, а не в строку
  a.style.display = 'block';
  a.textContent = link; // описание ссылки

  container.append(a); // добавляем тег в контейнер
});
```